# How do I formulate this complex database query with Django 3.0?

Tags: python, django, database, aggregate

I have the following table:

[image]

Now I want to group the data by `code`, have a `sum` of `visitors` and the `number of total nights` the visitors stayed for each.

I can do the first bit with this query:

```py
result = Entry.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values("code").annotate(
            total_visitors=Sum("visitors"))
```

This yields something along those lines:
`[{'code': 'AT - Wien', 'visitors': 2}, {'code': 'CN - China', 'visitors': 4}, ...]`

I would need something like this:
`[{'code': 'AT - Wien', 'visitors': 2, 'nights': x}, {'code': 'CN - China', 'visitors': 4, 'nights': x}, ...]`

Now the problem is the number of total nights they stayed. For each entry, I would need to do the following to calculate that: `nights = (departure - arrival) * visitors`

How do I do this the right way? I can do it in code and iterate over the individual entries but there has to be a cleaner way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here :

You should be able to create your own.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

Comment: Ah, thanks so far. I've been looking through that for a bit now but sadly am not completely clear how I would translate that for my problem. Could you give me another hand with that? Or have you never done this yourself before either?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using Django ORM:

Assuming that the Departure and Arrival are stored as date datatype.Here's what you should do:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
result = Entry.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values("code").annotate(
            total_visitors=Sum("visitors"), 
            nights=Sum(F("Departure") - F("Arrival")))
```

**And::**

To run the query (Departure - Arrival) * visitors we would need to create our own function like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Func
class DayDiff(Func):
    function = 'datediff'
    output_field = IntegerField()

Entry.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values("code").annotate(
                total_visitors=Sum("visitors"), 
                nights=Sum(DayDiff('Departure', 'Arrival')*F('visitors')))
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, looking good so far! I will also need to multiply by `visitors`, because the formula is `nights = (departure - arrival) * visitors`. How do I add this?

Comment: Oh, then `Sum(F("Departure") - F("Arrival"))` will change to `Sum((F("Departure") - F("Arrival"))*F('visitors'))`

Comment: Thanks again. Now I'm getting `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types: DateField, IntegerField. You must set output_field.`
. If I remove the multiplication, the result of the substraction is `'nights': datetime.timedelta(days=4)`.

Comment: To fix this we would need to create our own custom function.

Comment: Feared as much. Have you done this before and could lend a hand?

Comment: Feels like we're close, this is the issue now: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function datediff(date, date) does not exist` - `SUM((datediff("... HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` Error indicator points at `datediff`.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Postgres 11.3, I solved the issue with some code now. Thanks for your efforts but I think this'll do.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I am happy for you :)